# Ошибка "illegal command: java" при запуске майнкрафта

Tags: java, windows, minecraft, environment-variables

Скачал старую версию майнкрафта, писало ошибку:

```
illegal command: java
```

Установил версию Java 1.6.0, установил к ней путь в переменных средах, но майнкрафт все равно не запускается. Выдается та же ошибка. (майнкрафт запускается через bat-файл)

[image: это DosBox. в самом батнике просто pause]

То, что написано в bat-файле:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Djava.library.path="%CD%/natives" -cp "%CD%/minecraft.jar";"%CD%/jinput.jar";"%CD%/lwjgl.jar";"%CD%/lwjgl_util.jar" Start
pause
```

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: учту. спасибо..

Comment: _illegal command: java_ - говорит что такой команды нет. Проверь правильность установленных переменных.

Answer (score -1):

Тебе нужен JDK чтобы использовать команды "Java", ссылка на JDK: https://www.oracle.com/cis/java/technologies/javase-java-archive-javase6-downloads.html

Comment: В вопросе автор пишет, что он уже установил Java 1.6.0 и даже настроил необходимые переменные. Как ваш ответ должен помочь автору?

Answer (score -1):

Java Development Kit (сокращенно JDK) - это набор инструментов для разработки на языке Java. В него входят все компоненты, необходимые для того, чтобы программировать на этом языке. Он позволяет компилировать, то есть «собирать», и запускать написанный код.

Ссылка на скачивание с официального сайта:
https://www.oracle.com/cis/java/technologies/javase-java-archive-javase6-downloads.html

Comment: В вопросе автор пишет, что он уже установил Java 1.6.0 и даже настроил необходимые переменные. Как ваш ответ должен помочь автору?